# Http POST request returns body as json encoded in base64

Tags: http, http-post, httpresponse, exist-db

eXist-db POST request with authorization gives response that contains 2 items. First are headers and the second one is invisible. When I put it in string() function then it reveals as base64 binary string that contains json.
Json is format default type (and propably the only one) that API im connected to sends authorization data.

I tried to check if some headers are added by eXist but seems like nothing is wrong. Used request catcher and got that data:

```
OST / HTTP/1.1
Host: endpoint.requestcatcher.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Authorization: Basic OWJhMT...
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: code
Status-Only: false
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/12.0.1)
```

This is my function code:

```
declare function auth:get-access-token() {
    let $accessTokenResponse :=
    hc:send-request(<hc:request method = 'post' href='https://endpoint.requestcatcher.com'>
    <hc:header name = 'Authorization' value = 'Basic { $auth:base64credentials }'/>
    <hc:header name = 'status-only' value = 'false'/>
     </hc:request>)
    return $accessTokenResponse
```

};

The actual result is that response body contains base64 encoded string that contains json data.

I would like to receive json data that is originally sent by API authorization endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that your API returns JSON, you can handle the Base64-encoded response body simply by passing it to [`util:binary-to-string()`](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/view.html?uri=http://exist-db.org/xquery/util#binary-to-string.1) and then, assuming you want parsed JSON rather than raw text, to [`fn:parse-json()`](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/view.html?uri=http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#parse-json.1).

Here is sample code showing some additional logic for handling the response. Some remarks:

1. I'm using a sample endpoint that returns JSON.
2. It checks the response to ensure a 200 response; if not, it returns just the status and message as a map.
3. It handles various cases of response body types as outlined in the [EXPath HTTP Client](http://expath.org/spec/http-client#d2e483) spec.
4. It takes the additional step with JSON bodies of parsing the JSON.

The code:

```
xquery version "3.1";

import module namespace http = "http://expath.org/ns/http-client";

let $url := "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
let $response := http:send-request(<http:request method = "get" href="{$url}"/>)
let $head := $response[1]
let $body := $response[2]
let $media-type := $head/http:body/@media-type => tokenize("; ") => head()
return
    if ($head/@status eq "200") then
        (: When the response body contains XML or HTML, it is parsed into a document node. :)
        if ($body instance of document-node()) then
            $body
        (: When the media type is text/*, convert the Base64Binary body to string :)
        else if (starts-with($media-type, "text/")) then
            $body => util:binary-to-string()
        (: Parse JSON into XDM :)
        else if ($media-type eq "application/json") then
            $body => util:binary-to-string() => parse-json()
        (: Assume the body is just binary :)
        else
            $body
    else
        map { 
            "status": $head/@status => string(), 
            "message": $head/@message => string()
        }
```

The response on my system:

```
map {
    "userId": 1.0e0,
    "completed": false(),
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "id": 1.0e0
}
```

The benefit of parsing the JSON is that you can query the result, e.g., `$result?title` would return `"delectus aut autem"`.

Comment: Unfortunately ultimate goal is to maintain one xquery module that will work with basex, exist and propably 1 more db so additional parsing is not an option. I found some mimetypes config file that maps JSON to type=binary. Tried to changed it to:  <mime-type name="application/json" type="application/json">
        <description>JSON document</description>
        <extensions>.json</extensions> but still doesnt work and returns encoded base64 string

Comment: The only eXist-specific function is `util:binary-to-string()`, and BaseX's equivalent is `convert:binary-to-string()`. We can certainly work out a way to make this cross-platform compatible. But I'm not clear from the rest of your comment whether my code works or not for you? If it doesn't work for you, please let me know the error, etc. If it does work for you and the only issue is cross-platform compatibility, let me know.

Comment: Yes, your code works for me and I dont have any issues with eXist I guess. My only problem is compatibility. REST API I mentioned sends data as JSON only. I thought about overriding one method to achieve same implementation but it doesnt sound right approach. Maybe forcing BaseX to receive json as binary and then converting it to json/xml in both but again its converting json to binary jut to get json or xml again.

Comment: Ok, now I get it. The code in my answer works for my sample API, but not for your the API you're trying to reach. My guess is that something about that server's response header is not standard, and we may need to override the server's stated `media-type`. Try adding `override-media-type="text/text"` to the `<request>` element. Does that work with your API? If not, please post the actual response headers from your REST API here or as a gist.

Comment: Work on both but... Here is a simple function that i try to perform. api returns json by default. The goal is to use one module in basex and exist. The perfect solution would be to make exist return plane json as it is sent. If I would have to look up whether its json content-type header and if it is then parse  its not working in BaseX since BaseX treats JSON as JSON not binary data. https://gist.github.com/Tomasz9248/4dbbf82f7502bc6b665da9356357aeb8

Comment: Sorry, did `override-media-type` work or not with your API? I'm happy to help with BaseX once we get eXist working, but to be fair, your question specified eXist, and my answer provides code that works in eXist and does what you asked. So I'd appreciate it if you help me confirm that my answer also works for your API in eXist. (It's worth noting that while both eXist and BaseX implement the EXPath HTTP Client, they do interpret JSON response bodies differently. Hopefully we can clarify these differences with the devs of each and achieve cross-platform compatibility. But 1st things 1st!)

Comment: @Tomasz if you are using the EXPath HTTP Client in both eXist-db and BaseX then how it should return data to you is defined by the EXPath HTTP Client specification. If BaseX and eXist-db are not returning the same thing for the same API call, then one of them is incorrect with regards to the specification. The EXPath HTTP Client determines the output type fro the `Content-Type` header of the response, or as @joewiz pointed out by overriding that with `override-media-type `. Looking at your response, it says `Content-Type: code` which is junk, it should be an IANA Internet Media Type.. fix that